# Attempt to invoke virtual method getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: mysql, sql, android-studio

what dos this error mean? and how can I fix it?

I am trying to save data into my database, but I want to check if there already data exist there. and if there is, I want to update it.

Thank you for your help! It will be highly appreciated!

---

LogCat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

        at com.musicapp.android.musicapp.SQLDataBase.App_Theme_Color(SQLDataBase.java:220)
        at com.musicapp.android.musicapp.Settings.ThemeCustomAdapter$1$1.run(ThemeCustomAdapter.java:50)
```

CODE:

```
    public void App_Theme_Color(int color1, int color2, int color3) {
220        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_01,color1);
        contentValues.put(COL_0002,color2);
        contentValues.put(COL_0003,color3);
        String query = (" SELECT " + COL_01 + "," + COL_0002 + "," + COL_0003 + " FROM " + Table_Name3);
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0){
            String updateQuery = (" UPDATE " + Table_Name3 + " SET " + COL_01 + " ='" + color1 + " '" + "," + COL_0002 + " ='" + color2 + " '" + "," + COL_0003 + " ='" + color3 + " '");
            db.update(Table_Name3,contentValues," WHERE",null);
            db.execSQL(query);
            db.execSQL(updateQuery);
        }else{
            db.insert(Table_Name3,null,contentValues);
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code at line 220, you cannot call `getReadableDatabase` on `this`, as `getReadableDatabase` is a method that belongs to the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class. You must instantiate an object of `SQLiteOpenHelper,` or some sub-class of it, and then call this method on that object.